# How does Shopware handle the cookie path configuration for stores in different subdirectories?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

We have two different saleschannels/shops running on the same domain in different subdirectories. Let's say the domain is example.com, then one shop in one saleschannel is accessible with example.com/de, the other one with example.com/en.
We need two different saleschannels, because the catalog and category-tree differs for those two just to name one reason.

I inspected the cookies set from shopware/symfony and observed that on both shops the cookie-path is set to "/". This leads to one not being able to have a valid sessions in both shops simultanously.

Is there a configuration that we are missing? It seems to me that Shopware should set the cookie path by taking the current saleschannel-domain into consideration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up sales channels in virtual sub-directories is not preferable and prone to issues like that. If you can, you should save yourself the troubles and consider to set up sub-domains for the other sales channels. All you would have to do is point the sub-domains to the same `public` directory.

If you absolutely must stick with the path approach, you will have to do some adjustments. You could in theory have a subscriber that changes the `session.cookie_path` setting on the fly, based on the current base path. ([source](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/35465#issuecomment-621915112)) I haven't tested it though and even if it works, I personally would still advice against doing it.

```php
class SetSessionPathSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @var SessionStorageInterface 
     */
    private $storage;


    public function __construct(SessionStorageInterface $storage)
    {
        $this->storage = $storage;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [KernelEvents::REQUEST => ['onKernelRequest', 130]];
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event): void
    {
        if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
            return;
        }

        if (!$this->storage instanceof NativeSessionStorage) {
            return;
        }

        $options = ['cookie_path' => $event->getRequest()->getBasePath() ?: '/'];
        $this->storage->setOptions($options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! We know that this is not the optimal setup and also advised to use subdomains, but the business-decision was to use paths. So we will try to use your suggested approach and see if this works out.

Comment: Although it's not preferable, there are still use cases which require such a setup. And since it is possible in Shopware to setup two sales channels with the same domain, maybe we should create a ticket in Shopware to either fix the cookie handling or disallow the use of the same domain in multiple channels?

Comment: The use case for the path is [mentioned explicitly](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/settings/saleschannel#domain) to be for different languages within one sales channel. That's where a shared session is desirable and to be expected. Not so for different sales channels.